# Importing .dot file as subgraph

Tags: graphviz, dot

Is there -- either via a language feature or via a preporcessor -- a possiblity to include external .dot files as subgraphs into another one?

I am working on a relatively big graph, though manually maintained, not generated.

It would be convenient to be able to define some

`subgraph01.dot`:

```
digraph subgraph01 {
 /* lot of nodes and edges */
}
```

`subgraph02.dot`:

```
digraph subgraph02 {
 /* lot of nodes and edges */
}
```

And then do something like `graph.dot`:

```
digraph BigGraph {
    import subgraph01;
    import subgraph02;
    A -> subgraph01.Node1
    A -> subgraph02.Node1
    subgraph01.Node10 -> subgraph02.Node99
    /* etc. */
}
```

Is there a way?

Answer (score 18, accepted):

Two options immediately occur to me. One would be to use a macro processor, e.g. [m4](http://www.gnu.org/software/m4/). Given `BigGraph.m4`:

```
digraph BigGraph {
    define(`digraph',`subgraph')
    include(`subgraph01.dot')
    include(`subgraph02.dot')
    A -> subgraph01.Node1
    A -> subgraph02.Node1
    subgraph.Node10 -> subgraph.Node99
    /* etc. */
}
```

... running:

```
$ m4 BigGraph.m4
```

... produces:

```
digraph BigGraph {
    subgraph subgraph01 {
 /* lot of nodes and edges */
}


    subgraph subgraph02 {
 /* lot of nodes and edges */
}


    A -> subgraph01.Node1
    A -> subgraph02.Node1
    subgraph.Node10 -> subgraph.Node99
    /* etc. */
}
```

Another option that might allow a more sophisticated approach is to use 
[gvpr](http://www.graphviz.org/pdf/gvpr.1.pdf) from GraphViz. I tried to create an example to do this with `gvpr`, however and I was unsuccessful, so I suggest only trying it if a graph-aware approach is required rather than the simple approach using `m4`.

Comment: Is there any documentation on this?

Comment: @DazBaldwin  There is documentation on using `gvpr` and on using `m4` but not explicit documentation on using `m4` to process `dot` files, to my knowledge.