# Graphviz: automatic variables?

Tags: graphviz, dot

Suppose I define a node:

```
"somenode" [xlabel="somenode"]
```

Is there an automatic variable, as in `make` such that I can write, for example (in pseudo code) something like:

```
"somenode" [xlabel=$@]
```

Comment: `m4` may come to the rescue, see [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46595101/how-can-i-create-named-edge-types-in-graphviz-dot-neato/46872510#46872510)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use [**graphviz-py**](https://github.com/Alwinator/graphviz-py) to make a variable.

### Code

```
digraph g {
{{ some_node_name = "somenode" }}

"{{= some_node_name }}" [xlabel="{{= some_node_name }}"]

}
```

### Output

[image: Output]

Comment: I like it. I might also try `envsubst` if I had this problem again.  Can't remember the exact context of the question.

Answer (score 2):

If attribute supports type [escString](https://graphviz.gitlab.io/docs/attr-types/escString/) (which `label` attribute does) you can use `\N` for node name and `\G` for graph name. On edge label you can use `\T` for tail node name and `\H` for head node name.

```
digraph {
    Node1 [xlabel="\N"]
    Node2 -> Node3 [xlabel="\T" label="\H"]
}
```

Result:

[image]